# Xcode project failed to archive: undefined symbol of firebase_app_csharp

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine, cocoapods

I have a project developed by Unity which is using Firebase plug-in. I want to upload an ios build to Testflight on my ipad. While archiving it, it failed with Undefined symbol errors about Firebase_App_CSharp, just like this:

*Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_AppEnableLogCallback*

There are total 109 errors which are all Firebase_App_Csharp errors. I tried to build and run directly from xcode and activate the developer mode on my ipad, but I still got these same errors.

The database functions worked well in Unity Editor. I'd really appreciate it if there could be any insights about this issue.

---

***Update***

After 10 hours of research, I figured out something but still couldn't make the build.

Seems like bugs come from cocoapods which couldn't be downloaded. I followed the tutorials below to set up the environment for it:

- [The fastest and easiest way to install Ruby on a Mac in 2023](https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/#configure-your-shell)
- [How to Resolve iOS Framework Addition Failed due to cocoaPods Installation Failure in Unity iOS.](https://youtu.be/zdv9qE4j-VU?si=5fkQMvaO2EukceTi)

I got pods downloaded and I can see them generated successfully. I got a .xcworkspace file but when I tried to build the project, it gave me the same errors just like before.

Then I went back to build from the .xcodeproj file, undefined symbol errors disappeared but I got 2 new errors which are:

```
ld: framework not found FBLPromises
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Did I fail to download the pods? Or is there anything missing from the dev environment... This thing really confused and frustrated me. Any insights would be really appreciated.

---

Something confuses me but not sure whether it is relevant:

After downloading Xcode, Unity shows me the same error every time.

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qDUW.png)

After I set up homebrew, updated ruby and activesupport. Unity still gave me the same error every time I opened the project. I can see Ruby is up to date from the terminal but Unity seems not get the update at all.

---

Here are the errors:

```
Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_AppEnableLogCallback

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_AppGetLogLevel

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_AppOptionsInternal_ApiKey_get

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_AppOptionsInternal_ApiKey_set

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_AppOptionsInternal_AppId_get

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_AppOptionsInternal_AppId_set

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_AppOptionsInternal_GetDatabaseUrlInternal

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_AppOptionsInternal_LoadFromJsonConfig__SWIG_0

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_AppOptionsInternal_LoadFromJsonConfig__SWIG_1

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_AppOptionsInternal_MessageSenderId_get

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_AppOptionsInternal_MessageSenderId_set

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_AppOptionsInternal_PackageName_get

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_AppOptionsInternal_PackageName_set

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_AppOptionsInternal_ProjectId_get

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_AppOptionsInternal_ProjectId_set

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_AppOptionsInternal_SetDatabaseUrlInternal

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_AppOptionsInternal_StorageBucket_get

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_AppOptionsInternal_StorageBucket_set

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_AppOptionsLoadFromJsonConfig

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_CharVector_Add

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_CharVector_AddRange

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_CharVector_Clear

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_CharVector_Contains

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_CharVector_GetRange

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_CharVector_IndexOf

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_CharVector_Insert

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_CharVector_InsertRange

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_CharVector_LastIndexOf

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_CharVector_Remove

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_CharVector_RemoveAt

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_CharVector_RemoveRange

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_CharVector_Repeat

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_CharVector_Reverse__SWIG_0

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_CharVector_Reverse__SWIG_1

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_CharVector_SetRange

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_CharVector_capacity

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_CharVector_getitem

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_CharVector_getitemcopy

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_CharVector_reserve

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_CharVector_setitem

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_CharVector_size

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_CheckAndroidDependencies

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_ExportFix

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FirebaseApp_AppSetDefaultConfigPath

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FirebaseApp_CreateInternal__SWIG_0

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FirebaseApp_CreateInternal__SWIG_1

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FirebaseApp_CreateInternal__SWIG_2

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FirebaseApp_DefaultName_get

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FirebaseApp_GetApps

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FirebaseApp_GetLogLevelInternal

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FirebaseApp_IsDataCollectionDefaultEnabledInternal

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FirebaseApp_LogHeartbeatInternal

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FirebaseApp_NameInternal_get

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FirebaseApp_RegisterLibrariesInternal

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FirebaseApp_ReleaseReferenceInternal

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FirebaseApp_SetDataCollectionDefaultEnabledInternal

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FirebaseApp_SetLogLevelInternal

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FirebaseApp_options

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FixAndroidDependencies

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FutureBase_Release

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FutureBase_error

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FutureBase_error_message

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FutureBase_status

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FutureBool_GetResult

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FutureBool_SWIGUpcast

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FutureBool_SWIG_FreeCompletionData

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FutureBool_SWIG_OnCompletion

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FutureString_GetResult

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FutureString_SWIGUpcast

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FutureString_SWIG_FreeCompletionData

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FutureString_SWIG_OnCompletion

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FutureVoid_SWIGUpcast

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FutureVoid_SWIG_FreeCompletionData

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FutureVoid_SWIG_OnCompletion

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_GetEnabledAppCallbackByName

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_GetLogLevel

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_InitializePlayServicesInternal

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_PollCallbacks

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_SetEnabledAllAppCallbacks

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_SetEnabledAppCallbackByName

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_SetLogFunction

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_SetLogLevel

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_StringList_Add

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_StringList_AddRange

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_StringList_Clear

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_StringList_Contains

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_StringList_GetRange

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_StringList_IndexOf

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_StringList_Insert

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_StringList_InsertRange

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_StringList_LastIndexOf

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_StringList_Remove

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_StringList_RemoveAt

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_StringList_RemoveRange

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_StringList_Repeat

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_StringList_Reverse__SWIG_0

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_StringList_Reverse__SWIG_1

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_StringList_SetRange

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_StringList_capacity

Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_StringList_getitem

Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```